# How can one select elements from a list that are satisfied a criteria which need to compare with other elements in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example:
I want to select elements from a list {1,4,3,2,5} that are bigger than **its previous element**.
{4,5} satisfies the criteria: 4 is greater than 1 and 5 is greater than 2(Ignore the first element).

In general,
Is there any simple way to select elements from a list that are satisfied a criteria which need to compare with other elements in the list?

Comment: Something like `First /@ Split[{1, 4, 3, 2, 5}, Greater] // Rest`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@belisarius comment is pure genius, but if you need more flexibility for your criteria take a look at v10's amazing `MovingMap`

```
list={1,4,3,2,5};

(* Find elements greater than the one before *)
Pick[Rest@list, MovingMap[#[[1]]<#[[2]]&,{1,4,3,2,5}, {2}]]
(* {4,5} *)

(* Find elements smaller than the next one *)
Pick[Most@list, MovingMap[#[[1]]<#[[2]]&,{1,4,3,2,5}, {2}]]
(* {1,2} *)

(* Find a valley *)
Pick[Rest@*Most@list, MovingMap[#[[1]]>#[[2]]<#[[3]]&,{1,4,3,2,5}, {3}]]
(* {2} *)

(* Find a peak *)
Pick[Rest@*Most@list, MovingMap[#[[1]]<#[[2]]>#[[3]]&,{1,4,3,2,5}, {3}]]
(* {4} *)
```

You just have to mind the edges. You can either use a sensible padding or create a  function that handles the special cases!

Comment: +1 Still on V9 here, but `MovingMap[]` looks great. Hope the performance isn't lame. Anyway, at the expense of memory it can be simulated on previous versions with `f /@ Partition[list,n, 1]`

Comment: wow!Just updated my mathematica to V10, never seen `MovingMap[]` before,it's cool!

Comment: Well, took me only six years to discover MovingMap[].

Answer (score 2):

I prefer small steps. So try this:

```
list1 = {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};

list2 = Partition[list1, 2, 1];

list3 = Select[list2, #[[2]] > #[[1]] &];
```

output is: {{1,4}, {2,5}}

```
list3[[All, 2]]
```

output is: {4, 5}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};
```

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

Find elements greater than the one before

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} /; a < b :> b]
```

{4, 5}

Find elements smaller than the next one

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} /; a < b :> a]
```

{1, 2}

Find a valley

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; a > b < c :> b]
```

{2}

Find a peak

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; a < b > c :> b]
```

{4}

Answer (score 1):

Because I like Sow and Reap...

```
Reap[Fold[If[#2>#1,Sow[#2],#2]&,First[#],Rest[#]]&@{1,4,3,2,5}][[2,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};
```

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
(*Find elements greater than the one before*)

ReplaceList[Split[l, Less], {___, s : {a_, b__} /; a < b, ___} :> Last@s]

(*{4, 5}*)

(*Find elements smaller than the next one*)

ReplaceList[Split[l, Less], {___, s : {a_, b__} /; a < b, ___} :> First@s]

(*{1, 2}*)

(*Find a valley*)

ReplaceList[Split[l, Greater], {___, s : {a_, b_, c_} /; a > b, ___} :> Last@s]

(*{2}*)

(*Find a peak*)

ReplaceList[Split[l, Greater], {___, s : {a_, b_, c_} /; a > b, ___} :> First@s]

(*{4}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g[lis_] :=
  Module[
    {t1, t2},
    t1 = Partition[lis, 2, 1];
    t2 = Select[t1, #[[2]] > #[[1]] &];
    t2[[All, 2]]
  ]
```

Functional form of a previous answer